# Slider for chloropeth map Vega-lite

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-embed

I am trying to add a slider for my chloropeth map of Europe in vega-lite, to filter the data by year. I currently have a map which just shows data from 2019 (colour coded), and I am trying to make a slider so I can change years and see how the colours have changed over time.

Here is my code so far:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leakyMirror/map-of-europe/master/TopoJSON/europe.topojson",
    "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "europe"}
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "properties.NAME",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com//jamesjeffery77/jamesjeffery77.github.io/main/share-electricity-low-carbon_fullDataset.csv"
        },
        "key": "country",
        "fields": ["percentage"]
      }
    }
  ],
    "params": [
    {
      "name": "year",
      "value": 2019,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1985,
        "max": 2019,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "Select the year:"
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "naturalEarth1"},
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {
      "field": "percentage", 
      "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "properties.NAME",      "type": "nominal", "title": "country"},
      {"field": "percentage", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  }
}
```

I have been able to do make a bar chart using the same data which updates as I move the slider.The {"filter": "datum.year==year"} is what makes my bar chart able to do this, however it does not work on my chloropeth map (I have tried to add this within the "transform" array in both, with success for my bar chart). Here is the code for my bar chart in case that helps.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",

    "description": "",

    "title": {
      "text": "Thisisatest",
      "subtitle":
        "hellohello Source: OurWorldInData",
      "subtitleFontStyle": "italic",
      "subtitleFontSize": 10,
      "anchor": "start",
      "color": "black"
    },
  
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com//jamesjeffery77/jamesjeffery77.github.io/main/share-electricity-low-carbon_fullDataset.csv"
        },   
  
    "height": 300,
    "width": 350,

  "mark": {"type": "bar", "color": "skyblue"},
     
    "transform": [
      {"filter": "datum.year==year"},
      {"filter": {
          "field": "country",
          "oneOf": [
            "United Kingdom", "Spain", "France", "Netherlands", "Portugal", "Italy", "Poland", "Albania", "Germany", "Belgium", "Austria", "Denmark"]}
      }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "year",
      "value": 2019,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1985,
        "max": 2019,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "Select the year:"
      }
    }
  ],
      "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "percentage",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "title": "Percentage of low carbon energy",
        "axis": {"grid": false}
      },
      "x": {
        "field": "country",
        "type": "nominal",
        "title": "",
        "axis": {"grid": false, "labelAngle": 20},
        "sort": "-y"
      },
      "tooltip": [
        {"field": "country", "title": "Country"},
        {"field": "percentage", "title": "percentage of low carbon energy"}
      ]
    }
    
}
```

What am I am doing wrong? Would appreciate any help! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was almost correct but in your `lookup` transform you need to provide the fields which you are going to be required in your final data like `year` field. Since there was no year field the `filter` transform was not working.

Below is the modified config or refer [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemgDMABh1L4NMlm16lapJhSpQDAE6C0GbHkIE7SZdTqMmDCHB2UHKYcLKYlMEIRJJICHAQknAAZsmBAJ4A7JkEsfGJKWl2WZne9MysHMg0spwwSHZw-HCCcFCYdjRQdOlCbMr8UA1McgD6yQyCggAilkgBEVAQxCAAvkodSLIQyWx2CGgA2qCCbGwA1gw4TsEM4cWKIMl2bAc2IBZWaLYOTli4+CIHi8tHKfgCQRCYUWrwIrSQ53SAFkaHYXnYCMgcPw2MlmvY2DhRMgIKEMQAVQlsABSAGUAPIAOQIcAJRMomCp0jkj12+0s3xAmHSRKcnJwbG58iUaUs9jgTlZL1Fq3WIHOcHSThwysCmBoCUojIAgkiAKK8g2CNQQI4gHWEvUG20bEUKpRkOCvOAdLUAXVVClAyRogjJTk+DAQlHScAaAF547GGms-UocA04rbUMcQLI4gr0Mm7I9iEhBAxCwAmHQARgAnEomDU1IKajgGJgnB5ZJ7HggamgGwAOMRKZAADzQNd0SlJcGuqFrSnz8SctJabUwAAJ6HBt8X0Kq0-aXkl2ux5O9haL0PnMPZy2aGvRa2txw1zk5PWwIPVRUoYTBGoNRkIKwSnCW7whi0rboESQTQkgfaureIAAI4MFs+pWPqpDvkKZxhjQi65jB1rarqdj6oaJrmo8N6Fnmrw1OWDF0K0NxsHcvrvsGVpwfagRQEhKFCm6TiYdhdCWDQ+GrAGqxAA):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 300,
  "height": 300,
  "data": {
    "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com//jamesjeffery77/jamesjeffery77.github.io/main/share-electricity-low-carbon_fullDataset.csv"
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "lookup": "country",
      "from": {
        "data": {
          "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leakyMirror/map-of-europe/master/TopoJSON/europe.topojson",
          "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "europe"}
        },
        "key": "properties.NAME",
        "fields": ["properties", "type", "geometry"]
      }
    },
    {"filter": "datum.year==year"}
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "year",
      "value": 2019,
      "bind": {
        "input": "range",
        "min": 1985,
        "max": 2030,
        "step": 1,
        "name": "Select the year:"
      }
    }
  ],
  "projection": {"type": "naturalEarth1"},
  "mark": "geoshape",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"field": "percentage", "type": "quantitative"},
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "country"},
      {"field": "percentage", "type": "quantitative"}
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit**

I have inverted the main data and lookup data, which seems to bring all the years for your countries. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It doesn't seem to have worked for me - I only have the map for one of the years (2020) and the others don't show up :(

Comment: Other won't show up because the `loopup` you are performing, in that you don't have all the countries available. So, that's why you are getting limited data for the countries of Europe. For example: if you check Africa or Afghanistan then it is not part of your data `source_0` but its there in `source_1`, and souce_0 is being used in your chart.

Comment: Ah ok, is there any way to fix that - I only need the European countries for my map but I just need the data for all of the years?

Comment: If your European countries does not have years date other than 2019 and 2020 then how will it show for other years ?

Comment: they do have data, its just in source_1 rather than source_0.

Comment: Understood, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Yes this has worked perfectly thank you!