# Slider for choropleth map Vega-Lite

Tags: slider, vega-lite, choropleth

I want to make a slider (over time) for my choropleth map in Vega-Lite. I have made the slider and the choropleth map but they are not connected correctly. It seems that the choropleth map always shows the data from year 2021 instead of changing corresponding to the year on the slider. Any suggestions are appreciated - thanks in advance!

My code can be seen below.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "width": 800,
    "height": 400,
    "data": {
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarachristiansen/FIT_3179_DV2/main/Map_Combined_Worldwide.json",
      "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"}
    },
    "transform": [
      {
        "lookup": "properties.NAME",
        "from": {
          "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarachristiansen/FIT_3179_DV2/main/Emissions_by_Country_percapita.csv"
          },
          "key": "Country",
          "fields": ["Total", "Year"]
        },
        "as": ["Emission", "Year"]
      },
      {"filter": {"param": "year"}}
    ],
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "year",
        "value": 2000,
        "bind": {
          "input": "range",
          "min": 2000,
          "max": 2020,
          "step": 1,
          "name": "Select the year:"
        }
      }
    ],
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    "mark": {"type": "geoshape"},
    "encoding": {
      "color": {
        "field": "Emission",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {"type": "linear"}
      },
      "tooltip": [
        {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "Country"},
        {"field": "Emission", "type": "quantitative", "title": "Emission per Capita"}
      ]
    }
  }
```

I have also tried different variations of the filter definitions and "parse" but I am a complete beginner so I do not know what to look for. I have tried to implement it in the same way as here: [Slider for chloropeth map Vega-lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70557680/slider-for-chloropeth-map-vega-lite) but that did not work:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
    "width": 300,
    "height": 300,
    "data": {
      "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarachristiansen/FIT_3179_DV2/main/Emissions_by_Country_percapita.csv"
    },
    "transform": [
      {
        "lookup": "Country",
        "from": {
          "data": {
            "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clarachristiansen/FIT_3179_DV2/main/Map_Combined_Worldwide.json",
            "format": {"type": "topojson", "feature": "ne_110m_admin_0_countries"}
          },
          "key": "properties.NAME",
          "fields": ["properties", "type", "geometry"]
        }
      },
      {"filter": "datum.year==Year"}
    ],
    "params": [
      {
        "name": "Year",
        "value": 2019,
        "bind": {
          "input": "range",
          "min": 1985,
          "max": 2030,
          "step": 1,
          "name": "Select the year:"
        }
      }
    ],
    "projection": {"type": "equalEarth"},
    "mark": "geoshape",
    "encoding": {
      "color": {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative"},
      "tooltip": [
        {"field": "properties.NAME", "type": "nominal", "title": "country"},
        {"field": "Total", "type": "quantitative"}
      ]
    }
  }
```